# django.db.models get_models returning empty list in django1.4

Tags: django, menuitem, django-admin-tools

My code used to work in Django 1.3, but after the update to Django 1.4 it does not anymore.
The idea is to build a MenuItem for django-admin-tools, with a list of models from an app.

```
from admin_tools.utils import AppListElementMixin
from app import models as my_models

class CustomMenu(Menu):
    def init_with_context(self, context):

        app_list=AppListElementMixin()

        '''ERROR not working after upgrade to django 1.4, returns empty list'''
        all_models = get_models(app_mod=my_models)
        ''''''

        dict_models = {}
        for model in all_models:
            dict_models[model.__name__] = items.MenuItem(
                                            title=model._meta.verbose_name_plural,
                                            url=app_list._get_admin_change_url(model, context)
                                            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add your 'app' into settings.py INSTALLED_APPS
then do this

```
from django.db.models import get_models, get_app
```

and this

```
all_models = get_models(app_mod=get_app('app'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to add a menu item for each model, you can try:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from admin_tools.menu import items, Menu

class CustomMenu(Menu):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Menu.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.children += [
            # Other items that are in the menu eg "items.Bookmarks()," go here
            items.AppList(
                _('Name of the submenu'), # Your own choosing
                models=('app.models.*',) # Assuming your django app is called "app"
            )
        ]

    def init_with_context(self, context):
        return super(CustomMenu, self).init_with_context(context)
```

This is what I have working in one of my projects.

Comment: I used it, but I was trying to group the models under different group names and eliminate the app step in the Menu. What I can't understand is why is get_models returning an empty model after upgrading to Django-1.4